# SwiftUI List seems to add padding to internal elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list app and seem to be running up against some List View idiosyncracies. I have a View that produces this:

[image]

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Wash the laundry")
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("9 days ago", systemImage: "calendar")
                Spacer()
                Label("No assignee", systemImage: "person.fill")
                    .labelStyle(.trailingIcon)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

And yet when I put it into a list, it comes out like:

[image]

```
struct TestListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                TestView()
            }
            .navigationTitle("All Tasks")
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }
}
```

Note the extra padding around the calendar icon (and seemingly the entire bottom row) that it added. How do I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9 Days ago` label to add `.labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)`

Please try with below code and let me know it works for you

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Wash the laundry")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                HStack {
                    Label("9 days ago", systemImage: "calendar")
                        .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
                    Spacer()
                    Label("No assignee", systemImage: "person.fill")
                        .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .font(.caption)
            }
        }.listRowInsets(.init())
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Let me know if it's working for you or not.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Additionally, I also found out that you can accomplish the same thing using a simple HStack in a custom label style. This way, you can even preserve the colouring of the elements if you wish.

Comment: Okay, I will try

Answer (score 1):

`List` rows have default inset. You can get rid of it by setting an empty inset on rows:

```
List {
    TestView()
        .listRowInsets(.init()) //  Here
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the default inset value? I want to change the top and bottom insets on the row, but keep the leading/trailing defaults. The default is different depending on device size, so can't hardcode it.

Comment: Maybe adding a `.padding(.vertical)` is the closest similar look

Comment: @StevenStefanik were you able to figure out how to get the default insets? Thank you

Comment: @JohnCashew did not

Answer (score 1):

While you received an answer for the padding around the calendar icon, SwiftUI still insets your list rows' content by default.

To remove these insets, you can use [listRowInsets(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/listrowinsets(_:)) view modifier on the contents of your rows like this:

```html
struct TestListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                TestView()
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .navigationTitle("All Tasks")
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }
}
```